# Function works only after printing variables inside

Tags: warning-messages

For the input: pickTwoParts[{a, b, c}], the right output is: {{a, a b, a c, b, b c, c}, {b c, c, b, a c, a, a b}}. I am getting that output, but only after uncommenting the lines:

```
(*PrintOut["Length[parts]=",Length[parts]];
PrintOut["i=",i];
PrintOut["par1 before=",par1," and after=", Join[par1,pr1*parts[[i]]]];
PrintOut["par2 before=",par2," and after=", Join[par2,pr2]];*)
```

Otherwise I am getting the error message:

```
Set::write: Tag Times in Null {{},{}} is Protected. >>
```

The function code:

```
ClearAll[pickTwoParts];
pickTwoParts[parts_] := 
Module[{par1, par2, i, ret},
If[TrueQ[printPickTwoParts], 
PrintOut["pickTwoParts: parts=", parts], {}];

ret = {{}, {}};
If[Length[parts] < 2, Return[ret], {}];
(*Pick any one part and put it into parts1*)

par1 = {};
par2 = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[parts], i++,
 Module[{pr1, pr2, j, result},
  pr1 = parts[[i]];
  pr2 = 1;

  For[j = 1, j <= Length[parts], j++, 
   If[j != i, pr2 = pr2*parts[[j]], {}]];

  (*
  par1=Append[par1,pr1];
  par2=Append[par2,pr2];
  *)
  If[Length[par1] == 0,
   Module[{},
    par1 = {pr1};
    par2 = {pr2};
    ],
   Module[{},
    par1 = Append[par1, pr1];
    par2 = Append[par2, pr2];
    ],
   ];
  pr1 = {};
  pr2 = {};
  (*result=pickTwoParts[Delete[parts,i]];
  If[TrueQ[result\[Equal]Null],
  Module[{},
  pr1={};
  pr2={};
  ],
  {pr1,pr2} = result];*)
  (*PrintOut["pr1=",pr1," pr2=",pr2];*)
  {pr1, pr2} = pickTwoParts[Delete[parts, i]];

  (*Append the lists*)
  If[Length[pr1] > 0 && Length[pr2] > 0,
   Module[{},
    (*PrintOut[pr1,pr2];*)
    pr1 = DeleteDuplicates[pr1];
    pr2 = DeleteDuplicates[pr2];

    (*PrintOut["Length[parts]=",Length[parts]];
    PrintOut["i=",i];
    PrintOut["par1 before=",par1," and after=", Join[par1,pr1*
    parts[[i]]]];
    PrintOut["par2 before=",par2," and after=", Join[par2,pr2]];*)


    par1 = Join[par1, pr1*parts[[i]]];
    par2 = Join[par2, pr2];
    par1 = DeleteDuplicates[par1];
    par2 = DeleteDuplicates[par2];
    ]
   ,
   {}];
  ]
 ]

(*PrintOut["For input: ", parts, " returning: ", {par1,par2}];*)
ret = {};
ret = Append[ret, par1];
ret = Append[ret, par2];
Return[ret];

If[TrueQ[printPickTwoParts], 
PrintOut["pickTwoParts: returning=", ret], {}];
ret
(*Return[{par1,par2}];*)

]
```

Comment: What is the definition for `PrintOut`? It's not a built-in function.

Comment: Sorry, it's just Print, I made a custom version for silent runs.

Comment: You missed a semicolon after the closing square bracket of `For`, right above the line `ret = {};`. The error is what it is because `a b` means "multiply a by b" i.e. `Times[a,b]`. However multiplication doesn't work in the situation that you created by mistake.

Comment: I added the semicolon and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Working with a new *Mathematica* session and cleaning up your code to

```
pickTwoParts[parts_] :=
  Module[{par1, par2, i},
    If[Length[parts] < 2, Return[{{}, {}}]];
    par1 = {};
    par2 = {};
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[parts], i++,
      Module[{pr1, pr2, j, result},
        pr1 = parts[[i]];
        pr2 = 1;
        For[j = 1, j <= Length[parts], j++, 
          If[j != i, pr2 = pr2*parts[[j]], {}]];
        If[Length[par1] == 0,
          Module[{}, 
            par1 = {pr1};
            par2 = {pr2};],
          Module[{}, 
            par1 = Append[par1, pr1];
            par2 = Append[par2, pr2];]];
        pr1 = {};
        pr2 = {};
        {pr1, pr2} = pickTwoParts[Delete[parts, i]];
        If[Length[pr1] > 0 && Length[pr2] > 0,
          Module[{},
            pr1 = DeleteDuplicates[pr1];
            pr2 = DeleteDuplicates[pr2];
            par1 = Join[par1, pr1*parts[[i]]];
            par2 = Join[par2, pr2];
            par1 = DeleteDuplicates[par1];
            par2 = DeleteDuplicates[par2];]];]];
    {par1, par2}]
```

I encounter no problems when I evaluate

```
pickTwoParts[{a, b, c}]
```

> {{a, a b, a c, b, b c, c}, {b c, c, b, a c, a, a b}}

Mind you, I don't care for your rather clunky, pseudo-C coding style, but it certainly seems to work. I suggest your problem lies in the code that I removed. Since none of that code was needed, you're home free.

Comment: I did get that error message, but even if you didn't would you agree that `ret = Append[ret, par1]` is being multiplied by the preceding line as I mentioned in my comment? I use v10.1 and I have to fix that before your code works.

Comment: @Pickett. +1 -- but it does work in 10.1 even without the fix you suggest. I made the change.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick cigar-smoking interpretation to point you toward a more *Mathematica* flavored way.

A bit cleaner (IMO), and *much* faster. Does not check for length <2, etc., so add that.

```
With[{r = Range@Length@#, t = #, n = Length@# - 1}, 
   DeleteDuplicates /@ 
    Last@Reap[Scan[(Sow[Times @@ t[[#]], 1]; Sow[Times @@ t[[Complement[r, #]]]]) &, 
       DeleteCases[PadRight[Subsets[r, {1, n}]] // Sort, 0, 2]]]] &@target
```

Same results, and with e.g. a target of `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}` is over 5000X faster in a quick test against the cleaned-up version of your OP.

N.B.: I used operations against an underlying integer index into the *parts* (target), if your real-world case actually involves simply sorted unique symbols as in your example, can be made much simpler and faster still, e.g. ...

```
With[{s = DeleteCases[Sort[PadRight[Subsets[#, {1, Length@# - 1}]]], 
      0, {2}], t = #},{Times @@@ s, Times @@@ (Complement[t, #] & /@ s)}] &@target
```